# Work out the arc length of the curve $y = \frac12\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)$ between $\left[-\ln|2| , \ln|2|\right]$

Tags: arc-length

> Work out the arc length of the curve $y = \dfrac12\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)$ between $\left[-\ln|2| , \ln|2|\right]$.

I got this question in a math exam and I felt very defeated. Please can someone shed some light?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: You need to show some steps here. There is a procedure to set up an arc lenght integral. To begin with, derivative?

Comment: Is your function $y=\frac{1}{2(e^x-e^{-x})}$ or $y=\frac{1}{2}(e^x-e^{-x})$?

Comment: Agreed with @TomHimler. Edit as necessary.

Comment: Use the formula: $\int_{-ln(2)}^{ln(2)}(1+y'^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. I agree with imranfat, start by showing what you tried.

Comment: If you're looking for an elementary integral, don't bother, the integral evaluates to an [elliptic integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate_%28-ln+2%29%5E%28ln+2%29+%28+1%2F2+sqrt%282+cosh%282+x%29+%2B+6%29+%29+dx).

Comment: Tom Himler, its the second one you've given. That was pretty much all we were given. Plus we had a formula sheet with the well known Arc Length formula represented by Jo Jomax.

Comment: Are you sure it was $y = (e^x-e^{-x})/2$ and not $y = (e^x+e^{-x})/2$, The latter would be an easy calculation, but as GohPiHan indicates, the former is not.

Answer (score 0):

WolframAlpha gives the solution as

$$\int_{-\log(2)}^{\log(2)} \sqrt{1 + \cosh^2(x)}\ dx = -2 i \sqrt{2} E\biggr(i \log(2) \biggr|1/2\biggr)≈2.0437$$

On the other hand, following Paul Sinclair's suggestion ($e^x+e^{-x}$), then the solution is

$$\int_{-\log(2)}^{\log(2)} \sqrt{\cosh^2(x)}\ dx = \frac{3}{2}$$

I have verified these solutions numerically.